# Python indentation error in docker docs

Tags: python, docker

Attempting [Docker get-started example](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#apppy) I continue to get the indentation error message included at the bottom of this question and I cannot diagnose the problem. I have edited the copy/paste version from the link to "look like" the browser view and have replaced all Tabs with 4 spaces. But I do not understand the code itself well enough to know if the browser indented view looks like its meant to or not.

My version of the `app.py` code is as follows.

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)
```

The error is enclosed in the console session below.

```
server:docker0 brian$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
  File "app.py", line 15
    except RedisError:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
server:docker0 brian$
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: `IndentationError` normally means that there is a spacing problem. Suggest you delete all spaces and try again.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but get the same error. To be more specific, using vim I entered `:%s/    /^I/g` and then there were 3 spaces left in 2 different places, so I deleted them, also. There are 4 spaces between the slashes in the code here.

Answer (score 1):

While continuing to debug, as a test I deleted the word `RedisError` from the `except` line. But the error message still contained `RedisError`. That was my clue that the app.py I thought was being executed was not being executed. I had to execute `docker build ./ -t friendlyhello` again before I could `docker run`.